# Find the surface area of the shape formed by the boundary of $\frac{z^2}{4}=\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{4},z=2x+4y, z\geq 0$

Tags: calculus, geometry, analysis, multivariable-calculus

$$\frac{z^2}{4}=\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{4},z=2x+4y, z\geq 0$$
I know that this is a cone that is cut by a plane, but I do not know how to find the projection onto $xOy$. I need this because then I would have a base and I have the two graphs $z(x,y).$
I just want to know which shape it forms in it's base. Because I get $x^2+4xy+\frac{15}{4}y^2=0.$ I think I am supposed to get an eillipse but an ellipse has the equation $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1.$

Comment: I want to compute the surface area of the surface that is made up of this cone $\frac{z^2}{4}=\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{4}$ by this plane $z=2x+4y$

Comment: I am told to find the base of this shape some plane, either on $xOy,xOz,yOz$ and then use the $\sqrt{1+z_x^2+z_y^2}$ where $z(x,y)$ is the graph of the cone, and again I would use this for the plane, finding the integral upon, in this case the base (or projection) on $xOy$, or just $\int_{\text{base in xOy}}\sqrt{1+z_x^2+z_y^2}dxdy$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have trouble to understand what surface is meant here:

[image: the situation]
([Large version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjC1w.png))

Your first equation gives the cone (red), the second the plane and the third the half-space $z\ge 0$.

Comment: What program do you use for graphing this? I really need one. It seems to me that the profesor didn't set up the problem correctly, because this plane doesn't seem to cut out a "top" on this cone.

Comment: GeoGebra. Open a 3D view and directly enter the equations. It is available for many platforms. I use it on Win 7 and iOS9 and on Linux in the past.